# Get new tokens on Solana (realtime)

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli, solana-program-library

I want to obtain the token addresses of new tokens released on Solana that are compatible for swapping on Raydium.

I've explored various API providers, but unfortunately, none of them offer this specific data.

I experimented with Helius using the mainnet.helius-rpc.com endpoint, and I believe I'm headed in the right direction. However, I'm uncertain about which parameter I should input for my scope.

Is there any solution?